# jQuery mobile retrieving data between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile in a phonegap application and I'm trying to pass a variable from a textbox in to the next page to do an xml traverse with the variable.

My page has this javascript to send the variable through but I don't know how to retrieve it on the next page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#s-sur").live('pageinit', function() {

            $("#search").click(function() { 
                 $.mobile.changePage( "ssname.html", {
                type: "post",
                data: $("#search").serialize()
                                                        });
            });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssname.html` file will have to be parsed by a server-side language to get the POST variables. You can however access GET variables from JavaScript:

```
$("#s-sur").live('pageinit', function() {
    $("#search").click(function() { 
        $.mobile.changePage( "ssname.html", {
            type : "get",
            data : $("#search").serialize()
        });
    });
});
```

and then for the `ssname.html` page:

```
$("#ssname").live('pageinit', function() {
    //now you can get your variables from the URL: location.search
});
```

You could also just use a global variable to hold the information between pages:

```
$("#s-sur").live('pageinit', function() {
    $("#search").click(function() {
        window.myCustomVariable = $("#search").serialize();
        $.mobile.changePage("ssname.html");
    });
});
```

Then on the `ssname.html` page you can just read the `window.myCustomVariable` variable to do work. This works because the pages will occur in the same DOM, so the `window.myCustomVariable` variable will exist for both pages.