# How to pass parameters while changing the page in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've searched around stackoverflow but didnt find a proper solution to programmatically change the jqm page and pass a (get) parameter with it. I'm new to jqm so maybe I get something wrong on passing data with the changePage() function.

using jquery mobile 1.1.1 and jquery 1.8.0

I have a list and want all items to point to the same #profile page. on that page I want to load the appropriate data with ajax/json.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
   <li><a href="#profile">Martin</a></li>
   <li><a href="#profile?id=2">Johnny</a></li>   
   <li><a href="#" onclick="changePage()">Luke</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first link working, but no id is passed (obviously)

The second link ist not working throws exception (in chrome): Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #profile?id=3

The third link uses this function:

```
function changePage() {
            $.mobile.changePage("#profile", { data: {id:1} });
            //alert('page changed.'); 
            return false;
        }
```

It changes the page but the url is basefile.html?id=1 but it should be basefile.html#profile?id=1

Can anyone help with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made a small plug-in for jQuery Mobile so that pages can handle URL parameters if you're still interested. Works on jQM 1.3, about to upgrade the plugin for jQM 1.4.

Comment: @CameronAskew I'd be very interested in taking a look at that.... Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey ok, i'll throw it on github by the end of the day and give you a link..are you on jQM 1.4?

Comment: @CameronAskew Yes!, that'd be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey [Here is the link](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler)

Comment: See also this answer to a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35259962/3209859

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> As mentioned in the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html), jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to internal/embedded pages but there are two plugins that you can add to your project to support this feature. There is a lightweight [page params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) for use with backbone.js or spine.js.

There are other ways to implement the data passing during different pages but some of them may are not supported from old web browsers. You will have to select your implementation way carefully so that it does not induce consequences to the application's interoperability over multiple browsers.

You can pass data between different pages by using the **Web Storage**.

> As mentioned in the [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) site, with HTML5 web pages can store data locally within the user's browser. Earlier, this was done with cookies. However, **Web Storage** is more secure and faster. The data is not included with every server request, but used ONLY when asked for. It is also possible to store large amounts of data, without affecting the website's performance. The data is stored in key/value pairs, and a web page can only access data stored by itself. Web storage is supported in **Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari**. **Internet Explorer 7** and earlier versions, **do not support web storage**.
>
> There are two objects for storing data on the client:
>
> - localStorage which stores data with no expiration date
> - sessionStorage which stores data for one session

Examples:

**Local Storage Example:**

In Page1: localStorage.carType="test";
In Page2 you can retrieve the carType using: localStorage.carType

**Session Storage Example:**

In Page1: sessionStorage.carNumber=10;
In Page2 you can retrieve the carType using: sessionStorage.carNumber

Regarding your case, a possible solution is to add ids in each anchor. Then catch the click event, retrieve the id, save the id in the web storage and perform the page transition. In the next page retrieve the id from the web storage. Below you can find the implementation:

```
<ul id="menu_list" data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
   <li><a id="1" href="#">Martin</a></li>
   <li><a id="2" href="#">Johnny</a></li>   
   <li><a id="3" href="#">Luke</a></li>
</ul>


$('#menu_list').children().each(function(){
    var anchor = $(this).find('a');
    if(anchor)
    {
        anchor.click(function(){
            // save the selected id to the session storage and retrieve it in the next page
            sessionStorage.selectedId=anchor.attr('id');
            // perform the transition
            changePage();
        });
    }
});
```

**EDITED:**

**Alternative way to pass parameters when following a multiple pages approach**

This example uses `jQM changePage()` to send data with an Ajax page request.

```
$('#list-d a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.changePage('car-details.html', {
        data: {
            id: this.id
        }
    });
});
```

The constructed URL is .../car-details.html?id=my-id

For a complete example check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095634/dynamic-jquery-mobile-navigation/15100127#15100127)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you considered that you can simply save a JS variable when you leave one page, and then read the same variable when the next page is shown? Here is a basic example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502558/jquery-mobile-retrieving-data-between-pages/10503403#10503403. Also, I would be careful about reading-from or writing-to `sessionStorage` or any other type of browser implemented persistent storage in an event handler that handles user interaction. These read/writes take a lot of CPU and can take upwards of a second to complete on mobile handsets (which gives a negative UX).

Comment: Ok, but what will happen on a browser refresh? Using this approach all the data will get lost on a full page refresh. The approach with the JS variable is recommended when the page transitions are performed using the internal jQM AJAX functionality and there isn't any possibility of a page refresh.

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery Mobile normally and just having the links go directly to a server-side script that outputs a valid pseudo-page. Basically take-out the JS-initialized JSON step. That way you can just use links like this: `<a href="profile.php?id=2">Johnny</a>`.

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question was already answered and comments were traded on the answer, and I have also faced this issue. Using jQuery Mobile as it is intended allows for ajax loading, and therefore no need for a browser refresh unless instigated by a user, correct? And if a user is refreshing for some reason, that means that the site or app isn't functioning the way it is exptected to since most users wouldn't refresh without a frustrating cause.

In saying so, as suggested by the comments creating a variable is an efficient way of passing data from "page" to "page". However, my suggestion in doing so is to instead create a global variable to contain site information.

```
$('#elemControlToChangeBy').on("tap", function(oEvent)
{
   oMyNameSpace.PageDataObj = oDataObj;

   $.mobile.changePage("#elemPage", {transition : "type"})
});

$("elemPage").on("pageshow", function()
{
   var oDataObj = oMyNamespance.PageDataObj;

   //Use the data...
});
```

Obviously the code will have to modified to your coding conventions, but the concepts are there:

- Store your data or access it by some other means
- Place the data in a contained variable to prevent any overwrites by external code
- Access the data object variable when you arrive at the next page

There are other routes, as already stated(local storage, ect) so I won't go touching on that since the information is there already.

As stated above, I've run into this issue, and my suggestion is to use jQuery Mobile as it was intended and use your own code base to create and store variables using an organized object hierarchy. How you organize it is of your choice, which is precisely what makes javascript such a fantastic language.

We've become too dependent on libraries to solve simple issues that the authors leave to us to solve using our inventive and personal standard driven methods. Happy Coding to all, with an encouragement to build, not just design!