# Pass parameters in JQM- page refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile

i pass a parameter to a page, and retrieve using the data-url attribute, it works fine. But, if i refresh that page, the url parameter will not be available. What should be done for this. Pls help.

Comment: are you using single-page or multi-pages?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the url parameter in HTML5's `localStorage`. Generally, `localStorage` is supported by all browsers (including mobile) except IE, where it has some stability issues.

To store the url parameter,

```
window.localStorage.setItem("param", yourParam);
```

Then later, check if the item exists in the `localStorage`, if yes, get it from there and use.

```
if(window.localStorage["param"] != undefined)
{
  var param= window.localStorage["param"];
}
```

**Full workflow**

```
var param = "", local = window.localStorage;
if(local["param"] != undefined)
{
  param = local["param"];
}
else
{
 //store the param in a database/in the server session and retrieve from there.
 param = getFromServer();

 //set item in localStorage
 local.setItem("param", yourParam);
}
```

For more info, go to this <kbd>[link](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this issue is to check whether the `data("url")` contains a question mark `?`. If not you can retrieve the parameter values from the `window.location.href`.

This code:

```
$.mobile.changePage('car-details.html', {
    data: {
        id: 'my_id'
    }
});
```

creates the URL: .../car-details.html?id=my_id

The below code handles the case of normal transition and the case of page refresh. In case of page refresh the parameter value is retrieved from `window.location.href`

```
var passedId = (($(this).data("url").indexOf("?") > 0) ? $(this).data("url") : window.location.href ).replace( /.*id=/, "" );
```

For a complete example check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095634/dynamic-jquery-mobile-navigation/15100127#15100127)