# jQuery Mobile navigate - Why is the state empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, browser-history

I'm using `$.mobile.navigate("#test-page", {id:123})` to navigate to a secondary page.

The navigation from page to page works fine.... but the state is empty!

The docs clearly show that the state should contain all information I need when the navigation is performed.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(window).on('navigate', function(event, data) {
  console.log("navigated", data);
  console.log(data.state.info);
  console.log(data.state.direction);
  console.log(data.state.url);
  console.log(data.state.hash);
  if (data.state.hash === "test-page") {
    console.log("Test page", data.state.id);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately data is passed as empty:

```
{
    state:{}
}
```

The HTML is the following:

```
<div id="test-home" data-role="page">

      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Test Home</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
          <div id="test-btn">
            Click DIV for TEST page
          </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
      </div>

  </div>


  <div id="test-page" data-role="page">
     <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Test Page</h1>
     </div>

     <div data-role="content">
        Test page

     </div>
  </div>
```

---

Hope that someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: `state` is created when using browser navigation buttons (back/forward).

Comment: `state: Object hash: "#test-page" url: "file:///C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/experiements/navigation.html#test-page" ` when I move to '#test-page'.

Comment: @Omar thanks! I'll try changing a few things to figure out what is wrong... the dependencies are right off the CDN.

Comment: `state: Object direction: "forward" hash: "#test-page" pageUrl: "test-page" title: "Test Page" transition: "fade" url: "file:///C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/experiements/navigation.html#test-page"` when I click `back` and then `forward` to #test-page.

Comment: @Omar: is there any way of accessing the data without pressing back/forward?

Comment: I am not sure...tell me what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Omar: Wanted to create a router using navigate events. I guess it will probably be easier to do it separately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27411/discussion-between-omar-and-radianthex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.mobile.navigate` and `navigate` *event*, are used to track URL history and pass/fetch data from URL. They work with browser's navigation (back / forward).

To pass data between pages dynamically within a webapp using internal navigation, use `$.mobile.changePage`.

Resources:

- [$.mobile.navigate()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/)
- [Navigate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/navigate/)
- [$.mobile.changePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Use the below code to pass *data* from page to another.

```
$.mobile.changePage('store.html', {
 dataUrl: "store.html?id=123",
 data: {
    'id': '123'
 },
 reloadPage: true // force page to reload
});
```

To retrieve *data*

```
$('.selector').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 var values = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];
 id = values.replace("id=", "");
 console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: does the data and the data url have to match?

Comment: @CrimsonChin `dataUrl` to update browser location, `data` is used to send data to `ajax` function. In your case, fetch data from `dataUrl`.

Comment: but this then doesn't work with browser navigation (i.e. when pressing back/forward buttons)

Comment: @Kzar, true it's old. Use `pagecontainerbeforechange`  is safer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26393037/1771795 demo: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/send-additional-data-on-normal-ajax-link#14737000006599627

Comment: In fact, the querystring after the hash will be removed so the navigation back won't work. See my answer below for a better solution that works in all cases (btw, maybe it should be the accepted answer).

Comment: @Kzar you can choose whether to show or hide querystring by altering `data-url` of the page you're navigating to, all from `pagecontainerbeforechange`. Your answer is an alternative and I've +1 it. http://plnkr.co/edit/pD0EB3DtzlVLPLdOsqwg?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but @Omar's answer can be improved.

In fact, it is possible to use `pagecontainerbeforehide`, `pagecontainerbeforeshow`, `pagecontainerhide`, `pagecontainershow`, `pagecontainertransition` and `pagecontainerchange` (they are fired in this order) and inside the handler you can read the property `history.state`, that at that point is updated with the new state.

So, for example, you can write (to initialize things that need the page already formatted, e.g. Google Maps):

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, data) {
    console.log("pagecontainershow: " + JSON.stringify(history.state));     
});
```

This works in all cases: if you click on a link (with a hash, e.g. `#user`), if you navigate with the back and forward buttons, if you use `$.mobile.navigate` and also for `window.history.back()`.

Moreover, you can pass complex data, not limited to the query string constraints.

Resources:

- [Pagecontainer](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/)
- [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Reading_the_current_state)