# How to get query params for internal page link in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm looking for a clean way to do quite a trivial thing in JQuery Mobile.

When linking to an internal page to be loaded into the Dom, I want to read the query params.

So in the example below I want to access the id=test2 part of the url.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <a href="#page2?id=test2">Go to page 2</a>
</div>  

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <a href="#page1?id=test1">Go back to page 1</a>
</div>
```

I use pagecontainerbeforeshow to perform code on loading the page like this, but I don't know how to get to the query params.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "body" ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
        console.log("How to get the Query Params?");
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/wpgs06r1/6/

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Which parameters you want to load? Are you using single or multi-page model?

Comment: I edited it to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Mobile ignores (removes) *querystring* parameters in URL and shows URL with *hash* only. However, you can retrieve *querystring* only on [`pagecontainerbeforechange`](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/pagecontainerbeforechange/) and when `data.toPage` is a *string* not an object. At this stage, full URL is stored in `data.absUrl`.

You may use `$.mobile.path.parseUrl().search` method to retrieve *querystring*, or you can use `.split("?")`, both should work properly.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e ,data) {
   if (typeof data.toPage == "string") {
      var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.absUrl),
          querystring = url.search; /* retruns ?id=test1 */

      /* or */

      var url = data.absUrl,
          querystring = url.split("?")[1]; /* retruns ?id=test1 */
   }
});
```

Edit: If *querystring* comes after *hash*, `$.mobile.path.parseUrl(url).search` will return no value as it considers it a *hash*. Hence, use second method `.split("?")`.

---

Another possible way is to utilize `pagecontainerbeforetransition` as it fires once and returns `data.toPage` object and `data.absUrl` string.

Custom function to process URL and retrieve *querystring*

```
function getParam(url) {
    var parsed = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(url),
        hash = parsed.hash.split("?");
    return {
        search: hash[1].split("=")[1]
    };
}
```

Listen to `pagecontainerbeforetransition`; both `.toPage` and `.absUrl` should be defined and `.toPage`'s ID is the page you want to utilize parameters at.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforetransition", function (e, data) {
    if ($.type(data.toPage) !== "undefined" && $.type(data.absUrl) !== "undefined" && data.toPage[0].id == "pageID") {
        var param = getParam(data.absUrl).search;
        $(".selector", data.toPage).text("Retrieved: " + param);
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/0941gh6j/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is great. pagecontainerbeforetransition works better for me, because pagecontainerbeforechange gets triggered twice with each pageload.

Comment: @popovitsj you're welcome :) in next release of JQM `pagecontainerbeforechange` will trigger once and return a string.

Comment: Does the job! Good Answer.