# Phonegap + jQueryMobile passing url params

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

This seems like such a simple thing but the examples I'm finding all seem overcomplicated..

Say we have a basic Phonegap + jQueryMobile set-up, perhaps with the following structure:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously the hyperlink opens up the second page. Simple.

But if we want to pass a parameter to page 2 as part of that hyperlink, to be read via Javascript in the pageshow event, what's the correct method for this?

Just using href="?foo=bar#page2" or href="#page2?foo=bar" seems like the obvious solution to me, but window.location doesn't seem to see the parameters. Am I being thick?

I've seen examples that use onclick events to trigger a changePage() call and pass parameters that way, and I've seen regex trickery that doesn't seem to work for me, but surely there's a more proper, simple way using a traditional href?

Comment: you can do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26393037/1771795

Comment: For now, I'm using id's on the links and an onclick event that captures the ID of the clicked link into a JS variable that's within the global scope, so that the pageshow() event can just read from this. Of all the examples I've seen so far it's by far the simplest, but it just feels improper and flaky..