# jQuery mobile read query string from popup dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I found in google this question was asked several times. However, I haven't found right solution yet.

I have the following link element:

```
<a href='../Pages/WriteAbout.html?userName=Jacob' class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r' data-rel='dialog' data-transition: 'pop'>...</a>
```

When this link is clicked, a popup shows but when I read the url (in order to read the query string) I get the url without the query string 'userName'.

I read the url like this:

```
window.location.href
```

It seems like jQuery omits the query string from the url.

Is there any other way to pass parameter to a popup dialog? (`$.mobile.changePage(...)` is not a solution as it opens the page with no dialog popup)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26393037/1771795 Btw, dialog widget will be removed in jQM 1.5

Comment: Thank for your response, this is about page transitions. My question is about popup dialog. The are many differences between them, For example, popup dialog doesn't support 'pagecontainerbeforetransition' event.

Comment: It does, dialog triggers same page events. :-) edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wwmzum42/