# How to send object to another different page with Pagecontainer Widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Let's say I have more or less these files in my project:

- PageA.html
- PageA.js
- PageB.html
- PageB.js

I would like to change the page from PageA.html to PageB.html. Then, I used [Pagecontainer Widget](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/). Here is my snippet code in PageA.js to change the page:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "WorkOrderDetail.aspx", 
{ 
    transition: "slide", 
    objectA: objA 
})
```

Based on this [article](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/passing-parameters-between-pages-multi-page-model/), on the other side (PageB.js), I can get the `objectA` via `pagebeforechange` event like:

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforechange" , function ( event, data ) {
        var stuff = data.options.objectA;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(stuff));
});
```

Unfortunately, when I tried it, it even doesn't trigger `pagebeforechange` event at all when I move the page from PageA.html to PageB.html with Pagecontainer Widget. It only triggers the event when I refresh the pageB.html directly from the browser.

Therefore,

- is it possible to pass object between two different pages with Pagecontainer Widget?
- If yes, is there any concept that I missed?
- If no, is there any proper way to pass it while still using the transition effect of Pagecontainer Widget?

Comment: here is a deeper investigation of the JQM page events for external pages: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – Extra](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/)

Answer (score 1):

The article you mentioned is old and discussed *Multi-page model*, while you are using *Single-page model*. There is a difference in the technique followed to manipulate pages in MPM and SPM.

The pagecontainer widget was introduced in jQM 1.4; it is handy, yet requires more coding and trial & error process. Note that `pagebeforechange` is depreciated and replaced with `pagecontainerbeforechange`. Moreover, this event fires twice and returns **almost** the same data, as follows:

1. First time it returns `.toPage` value as a string
2. Second time `.toPage` is an object

In light of the above, you have to decide when to run your code, based on what data you want to retrieve and whether you want to do changes to previous or next page.

There are many ways to transfer and retrieve data between pages in jQM. For instance, data can be passed within jQM pagecontainer events, [query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393037/1771795), local storage ... etc.

In your case, you want to pass an *object* when changing pages.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "pageB.html", { objectA: objA } );
```

Since `pagecontainerbeforechange` is fired on every page change, you have to add some conditions in order to prevent your code from running whenever the event is fired. Also, to determine whether the data emitted is a `string` or an `object`.

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainerbeforechange" , function(e, data) {
  if (typeof data.toPage === "object" &&
    data.options.target === "pageB.html" &&
    data.options.objectA !== "") {

    var objectA = data.options.objectA, /* object passed */
        targetPage = data.toPage;       /* page you navigated to (jQuery object) */

    targetPage.find( ".foo" ).text( "objectA.bar" );

  }
});
```

Once you have both, the object of data and the object of the page you have navigated to, do the changes you want.

> **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dpn0nAb4NLeB7wZueFJ)**