# jquery mobile pass parameter along with div id href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, parameters

I have a jquery mobile app that uses 2 data-role=page divs.

```
<div data-role="page" id="main"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="det"></div>
```

On the link to switch from main to truckdet I use

```
<a href="#det">LINK</a>
```

Is there a way to pass a parameter in the `href` so I can dynamically extract data from a database and embed it in the `det` div?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058248/how-to-pass-parameters-while-changing-the-page-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: Have a look here: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/passing-parameters-between-pages-multi-page-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume you want to get data from DB using ajax and put content in desired div. Use this

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var url = your_url_here;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(value){
            target.html(value);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data thorough `href` like this.

```
<a href="#det?value=somevaluestobepassed">LINK</a>
```

I am not sure if it works for your case.